# excel formulation without VBA for sum of variable quantity of numerical values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to sum the vehicle and max hr intersection set for each subsystem. In other words I need to sum value of TRUEs and print the sum in the 1st FALSE which is above these TRUEs.

For example:

D1 = B2

D3 = B4+B5+B6+B7

D8 = B9+B10+B11

This is a simplified version of my real requirement. There exist thousands of data in my file. I don't know VBA. I also don't know which functions to use in this case, if it's possible to solve this without VBA.

which function(s) should I try?

regards.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
=IF(C1=FALSE;SUM(B2:B11)-SUM(D2:D11);"")
```

It sum ALL the number and subtract all the othr sum below...
Copy and paste for every cells. Make attention to NOT fix the cell ($) otherwise don't work...

[image]

It's NOT a very good solution, but work.